# Dockerize a Django app with a MySQL container

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker, docker-compose

I have an app developed in Django (2.2.7) with python (3.8.0), Docker (19.03.5) and docker-compose (1.25.2) running in Windows 10 pro. I want to Dockerize it with changing the sqlite3 database for a MySQL database. I've already write this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.7
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD . /code/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install mysqlclient
COPY . /code/
```

And this `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services: 
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
       MYSQL_DATABASE: 'my-app-db'
       MYSQL_USER: 'root'
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
    volumes:
      - .setup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initbd.d/setup.sql

  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links: 
      - db
```

Also I have change the default database configurations in `settings.py` for this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'my-app-db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 3306,
    }
}
```

After all of this the docker compose works and the app starts, but the problem is that the tables in the database are not created. I've tried with these [How do I add a table in MySQL using docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49828134/how-do-i-add-a-table-in-mysql-using-docker-compose), [Seeding a MySQL DB for a Dockerized Django App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44296536/seeding-a-mysql-db-for-a-dockerized-django-app) or this [Seeding a MySQL DB for a Dockerized Django App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44296536/seeding-a-mysql-db-for-a-dockerized-django-app) but I couldn't fix it yet.

How can I create the required tables in the MySQL db container while runing the docker-compose? Must I add every single table by hand or there is a way to do it from the django app automatically?

Thanks

Comment: You need to run migrations. `docker exec -it <web_app_id> bash` then run `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: I've already done that, ```No migrations to apply.``` The problem maybe is in the conexion with the db?

Comment: Hi Manual, what errors or info do you get back when you run `docker-compose up` in the terminal...

Comment: Hi, there is no error, everything seems to work and I can access to the loging page of the app, in fact I can access to the admin profile because the auth databases are created and I can create users from the admin or the command line. The probem are the other tables, the ones that I define in the project that for unknown reason are not created in the MySQL database.

Comment: Haven't you forgotten to mention the name of your app in INSTALLED_APPS in your `settings.py`?

Comment: No, I haven't. Everything works nice with the .sqlite3 database in local. The problems started since I try to put everything inside a docker container to take it to production, changing the original db for a MySQL one. I don't know what the problem is, but the must be connected since the auth information is in the new database, no?

Comment: Should be mapping the container names

Answer (score 2):

Hi i think this answer helps you
##1.- Reset all your migrations

```
find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete
find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
```

##2.- See and apply your migrations again

```
python manage.py showmigrations
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not reset your migrations unless you want to wipe all of the data completely and start over. Your migrations should exist beforehand. So if you dont mind about old migrations you can delete them and use `python manage.py makemigrations` and then proceed to following steps:

So if your applications starts at the moment, we need to update your docker-compose file in a way that it uses entrypoint.sh. An ENTRYPOINT allows you to configure a container that will run as an executable.
First things first, create your `entrypoint.sh` file on the same level as `docker-compose.yaml`.
Next, don't forget to add `chmod +x entrypoint.sh` so entrypoint can be executed

entrypoint.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

echo "${0}: running migrations."
python manage.py migrate --noinput

echo "${0}: collecting statics."

python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Afterwards update your `docker-compose.yaml` file. Change your `command` line to:

```
command:
  - /bin/sh
  - '-c'
  - '/code/entrypoint.sh'
```

Additionally you should store all of your pip requirements in `requirements.txt` file and in your `Dockerfile` you should run `pip install -r requirements.txt`

You can dump your pip requirements with a command `pip freeze > requirements.txt`